# Can't update table in Laravel 5.4 using Elequent query

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4. I made a function for  two (insert and update).
When id is not found it will hit insert otherwise it will hit the update method. 
Everything is working well but the update elequent query is not updating the table. The method is for angularjs http.post method

Controller function:

```
public function postUserJson(Request $req)
{
    //return "check". $req->input('id');

   if ($req->input('id')=='') {
        $user = new User();
        $user->UserName = $req->input('username');
        $user->Password = $req->input('password');

        $user->save();
       return "inserted";
   } else {
       $check= User::find($req->input('id'));

      // $check->ID = $req->input('id');
       $check->UserName = $req->input('username');
       $check->Password = $req->input('password');

       $check->save();
       return "updated".$check;
    }
}
```

This (`return "updated".$check;`) code return in console:

```
 updated{"ID":13,"UserName":"sadek","Password":"456"}
```

[image]

Previous username was sade. After editing i got the edited name with sadek after save() method. But when i refresh it show sade

How can i update a table ?

Comment: does your model have the correct fillable fields?

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    //
}`

Comment: fillable fields are in the model and shown as an array... Example:   protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name', 'gender', 'phone', 'email'];

Answer (score 0):

you are sending data in json formate. your query string is not same. see

```
"UserName" != username

Password != password
```

make sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent provides a method for handling all of the logic you have above, it is called `updateOrCreate()`

**From the docs:**

You may also come across situations where you want to update an existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides an `updateOrCreate` method to do this in one step. Like the  `firstOrCreate` method, `updateOrCreate` persists the model, so there's no need to call `save()`

```
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```